# LEFT JOIN в hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, запрос

Есть запрос

```
SELECT *
FROM [std].[dbo].[StudentProfile] A
LEFT JOIN [std].[dbo].[User] U 
ON A.[StudentID] = U.[UserID]
WHERE U.Usermail = 'a@a.com'
```

не нашел или не понял, как составить правильную "criteria"

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(StudentProfile.class);
criteria.createAlias("user", "User");
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("user.usermail", params.getEmail()));
```

тут на 2й строчке вылетает ошибка. может кто знает, как правильно составить?

Comment: Желательно в вопрос  добавлять полный stack trace ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы не указываете тип `join`, то, по умолчанию, используется `inner join`.

У Вас в запросе точное соответствие `usermail`.

Вы используете альяс с маленькой буквы в `user.usermail`.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(StudentProfile.class);
criteria.createAlias("user", "user", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("user.usermail", params.getEmail()));
```

В `StudentProfile` должна быть ассоциация с `User`. Например, `@OneToOne`.

Comment: спасибо. буду пробовать.